# Почему не работает implicit conversion

Tags: c++

почему код с `template<class T>` компилируется, а без него нет

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct a
{
    friend void operator+(const a&, int)
    {
        cout << "ddd";
    }
} A;

template <class T>
struct c
{
    operator a&() const noexcept
    {
        return A;
    }
    operator a() const noexcept
    {
        return A;
    }
};


int main()
{
    c<a> C{};
    C + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вы вынесите определение оператора из `a`, оставив там только объявление, и попробуйте еще раз... - https://ideone.com/dUth6H

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если функция объявлена только как `friend` внутри класса, то она формально принадлежит охватывающему пространству имен. Но при этом она *не видна* обычному процессу поиска имен, а может быть видна лишь ADL-поиску (Argument Dependent Lookup).

ADL-поиск делается через *ассоциированные пространства имен* и *ассоциированные классы*. Если один из аргументов имеет тип специализированного шаблона, то в список *ассоциированных классов* будут добавлены все типы аргументов этого шаблона.

В вашем примере поиск подходящего оператора `+` производится в глобальном пространстве имен. Один из аргументов `+` является специализацией шаблона `c` с аргументом `a`. Это приводит к включению `a` в список ассоциированных классов и к тому, что friend-функции этого класса становится видимыми с точки зрения ADL в глобальном пространстве имен.

Если вы уберете шаблонность, то класс `a` будет совершенно посторонним классом, никак не фигурирующим в выражении `C + 1`. Он не будет рассматриваться ADL в качестве ассоциированного класса и его friend-функции так и останутся "невидимыми".

---

Если вы дополнительно явно объявите свой оператор в охватывающем пространстве имен

```
struct a
{
    friend void operator+(const a&, int)
    {
        cout << "ddd";
    }
} A;

void operator+(const a&, int);
```

тот он будет виден сразу и всегда обычному процессу поиска имен. Зависимость от ADL (и от шаблонности) сразу исчезнет и код будет компилироваться.

Comment: после такого хорошего сочинения можно  не смотреть кто ответил... конечно AnT